# Using Metric equation for calculating BMI, how to convert imperial measurement using GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am new to Java and have to create a BMI calculator which allows the user to input metric or imperial measurements and calculate the BMI using one of the equations for calculating BMI.  I have used the metric calculation and I have the metric measurements displaying correctly.  I now need to convert the Imperial measurements into metric and then using the already existing metric BMI calculation, display the answer.  I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Font;

public class BMIFrame extends JFrame{
  // Create instructions label
  private JLabel instructions = new JLabel("<html>To calculate your Body 
     Mass Index (BMI), please "
    + "enter your weight and height in the fields provided in either 
  Imperial or Metric measurements.</html>");

    // Metric section labels and fields
    private JLabel metricHeading = new JLabel("Metric");
    private JLabel metricWeight = new JLabel("Enter your Weight:");
    private JTextField metTextWeight = new JTextField("0");
    private JLabel weightKg = new JLabel("kgs");
    private JLabel metricHeight = new JLabel("Enter your Height:");
    private JTextField metTextHeight = new JTextField("0");
    private JLabel heightCm = new JLabel("cms");

    // Imperial section labels and fields
    private JLabel imperialHeading = new JLabel("Imperial");
    private JLabel imperialWeight = new JLabel("Enter your Weight:");
    private JTextField impTextWeight = new JTextField("0");
    private JLabel weightSt = new JLabel("st");
    private JTextField impTextWeight2 = new JTextField("0");
    private JLabel weightLbs = new JLabel("lbs");
    private JLabel imperialHeight = new JLabel("Enter your Height:");
    private JTextField impTextHeight = new JTextField("0");
    private JLabel heightFt = new JLabel("ft");
    private JTextField impTextHeight2= new JTextField("0");
    private JLabel heightIns = new JLabel("ins");

    private JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate BMI");
    private JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    private JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

    private JLabel bmiInfoHeading = new JLabel("BMI Values");
    private JLabel bmiInfoUnder = new JLabel("Below 18.5 = Underweight");
    private JLabel bmiInfoNormal = new JLabel("18.5 - 24.9 = Normal");
    private JLabel bmiInfoOver = new JLabel("25.0 - 29.9 = Overweight");
    private JLabel bmiInfoObese = new JLabel("30.0 + = Obese");

    // create a this is your result label
    private JLabel bmiResult = new JLabel("Your BMI is ");
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField("0");

    public BMIFrame() {
        setLayout(null);

        // Add instructions
        instructions.setBounds(5, 5, 475, 38);
        instructions.setBackground(getBackground());
        instructions.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(instructions);

        // Add Metric heading
        metricHeading.setBounds(90, -25, 225, 200);
        metricHeading.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        add(metricHeading);

        // Add Metric Weight Label
        metricWeight.setBounds(5, 5, 225, 200);
        metricWeight.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(metricWeight);

        // Add Metric Weight input field
        metTextWeight.setBounds(120, 92, 50, 25);
        metTextWeight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(metTextWeight);

        // Add Kilogram label to weight field
        weightKg.setBounds(172, 5, 225, 200);
        weightKg.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(weightKg);

        // Add Metric Height Label
        metricHeight.setBounds(5, 40, 225, 200);
        metricHeight.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(metricHeight);

        // Add Metric Height input field
        metTextHeight.setBounds(120, 127, 50, 25);
        metTextHeight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(metTextHeight);

        // Add Centimetres label to weight field
        heightCm.setBounds(172, 40, 225, 200);
        heightCm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(heightCm);

        // Add imperial measurements fields
        imperialHeading.setBounds(330, -25, 225, 200);
        imperialHeading.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        add(imperialHeading);

        // Add Imperial Weight Label
        imperialWeight.setBounds(225, 5, 225, 200);
        imperialWeight.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(imperialWeight);

        // Add Imperial Weight input field
        impTextWeight.setBounds(335, 92, 50, 25);
        impTextWeight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(impTextWeight);

        // Add Stone label to weight field
        weightSt.setBounds(385, 5, 225, 200);
        weightSt.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(weightSt);

        // Add second Imperial Weight input field
        impTextWeight2.setBounds(400, 92, 50, 25);
        impTextWeight2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(impTextWeight2);

        // Add Pounds label to weight field
        weightLbs.setBounds(451, 5, 225, 200);
        weightLbs.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(weightLbs);

        // Add Imperial Height Label
        imperialHeight.setBounds(225, 40, 225, 200);
        imperialHeight.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(imperialHeight);

        // Add Imperial Height input field
        impTextHeight.setBounds(335, 127, 50, 25);
        impTextHeight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(impTextHeight);

        // Add Feet label to weight field
        heightFt.setBounds(386, 40, 225, 200);
        heightFt.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(heightFt);

        // Add Imperial Height input field
        impTextHeight2.setBounds(400, 127, 50, 25);
        impTextHeight2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        add(impTextHeight2);

        // Add Inches label to height field
        heightIns.setBounds(451, 40, 225, 200);
        heightIns.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(heightIns);

        // Add Calculate button
        calculateButton.setBounds(175, 175, 125, 50);
        add(calculateButton);

        // Add Clear button
        clearButton.setBounds(120, 360, 115, 30);
        add(clearButton);

        // Add Quit button
        quitButton.setBounds(240, 360, 115, 30);
        add(quitButton);

        // Result label
        bmiResult.setBounds(10, 240, 80, 50);
        add(bmiResult);

        // Add result field
        resultField.setBounds(86, 243, 80, 40);
        resultField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        resultField.setEditable(false);
        add(resultField);

        // BMI values display
        bmiInfoHeading.setBounds(345, 230, 80, 50);
        add(bmiInfoHeading);

        bmiInfoUnder.setBounds(300, 255, 200, 50);
        bmiInfoUnder.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(bmiInfoUnder);

        bmiInfoNormal.setBounds(300, 275, 200, 50);
        bmiInfoNormal.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(bmiInfoNormal);

        bmiInfoOver.setBounds(300, 295, 200, 50);
        bmiInfoOver.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(bmiInfoOver);

        bmiInfoObese.setBounds(300, 315, 200, 50);
        bmiInfoObese.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        add(bmiInfoObese);

        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
        calculateButton.addActionListener(bh);
        clearButton.addActionListener(bh);
        quitButton.addActionListener(bh);

    } // end of constructor

    // private inner class ButtonHandler
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == quitButton)
                System.exit(0);
            else if (event.getSource() == clearButton) {
                metTextWeight.setText("0");
                metTextHeight.setText("0");
                impTextWeight.setText("0");
                impTextWeight2.setText("0");
                impTextHeight.setText("0");
                impTextHeight2.setText("0");
                resultField.setText("0");
                return;
            }

            try {
                double metW1 = Double.parseDouble(metTextWeight.getText());
                double metH1 = Double.parseDouble(metTextHeight.getText());
                double impW1 = Double.parseDouble(impTextWeight.getText());
                double impW2 = Double.parseDouble(impTextWeight2.getText());
                double impH1 = Double.parseDouble(impTextHeight.getText());
                double impH2 = Double.parseDouble(impTextHeight2.getText());

                double result = 0;

                if (event.getSource() == calculateButton)
                    result = (metW1 / (metH1 * metH1) * 10000);

                String answers = String.format("%.1f", result);

                resultField.setText(answers);
            } // end of try method
            catch(Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(BMIFrame.this, ex.toString()
                    , "Error Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            } // end of catch method
        } // end of method actionPerformed
    } // end of inner class ButtonHandler
} //end of class BMIFrame
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different approach which should help to simplify the code.  Consider this interface:

```
public interface BMICalculator {
    public double calculate(double height, double weight);
}
```

And two implementations:

```
public class MetricBMICalculator implements BMICalculator {
    public double calculate(double heightCentimeters, double weightKilograms) {
      // convert as needed, calculate, and return...
    }
}

public class ImperialBMICalculator implements BMICalculator {
    public double calculate(double heightFeet, double weightPounds) {
      // convert as needed, calculate, and return...
    }
}
```

And within the UI have a units toggle to switch between metric and imperial.  This leads to needing only one weight entry field and only one height entry field.  When the toggle is triggered the text of the related labels are changed, and which implementation of the above interface is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add before the actual calculation:

```
metH1 = impH1*30,48;
metH1 += impH2*2,54;
metW1 = impW1*6,35;
metW1 += impW2*0,45;
```